# Apache Drill Plain Authentication throws Invalid Username/Password error

Tags: unix, authentication, centos, apache-drill, pam

I have setup Apache Drill version 1.15 in distributed mode on 3 nodes with ZK on the same 3 nodes.

Now, I am trying to configure Plain Authentication in Drill using PAM.
I already have 2 existing users in the 3 nodes with same password and they are present in **/etc/passwd** and **/etc/shadow**.

I have followed the steps mentioned [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/data_otaku/2016/06/10/setting-up-basic-user-authentication-in-drill/), to configure authentication setup on the Drill cluster.

But, on entering correct username and password, it throws `Invalid Username/Password` error.

My drill-override.conf looks like:

```
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "[cluster_name]",
  zk.connect: "[host1]:2181,[host2]:2181,[host3]:2181"
  security.user.auth: {
        enabled: true,
        packages += "org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.security",
        impl: "pam",
        pam_profiles: [ "sudo", "[profile1]", "[profile2]" ]
  }
}
```

I have set, `user1` as an admin and `user2` as normal user.

Is it that Drill, doesnt work with existing Users in the linux system and wants users to be created explicitly (which i really doubt), or anything else that I am missing?

Comment: The drillbit user (user used to start the drillbit process) should have permission to read /etc/shadow file so that it can authenticate other users. You can try adding the drillbit user to shadow group if not done and see if it helps. If it still fails, you can validate the pam profiles using pamtester if it can be installed.

http://pamtester.sourceforge.net/
command : pamtester -v <profile> "<user>" "authenticate" 

For sudo profile - pamtester -v sudo "user1" "authenticate" . 

Usually /var/log/secure file has authentication failure related logs.

Answer (score 2):

`pam_profiles` is array of PAM profiles, not users.

Example of `pam_profiles` configs: `pam_profiles: [ "sudo", "login" ]`. See details in [doc](https://drill.apache.org/docs/using-jpam-as-the-pam-authenticator/).

You can add other PAM profiles from your `/etc/pam.d`.

Comment: correct. I realized that after posting. I have updated the question with current config. But without any success!

Comment: You have left `I have set, user1 as an admin and user2 as normal user.` in the post.
Please post your actual config. `login` profile should be present there. Then retry.

Comment: Also please provide the following info: did you configure libjpam.so, did you set `DRILLBIT_JAVA_OPTS` config, did you restart your Drillbits?

Comment: For anyone coming here later, the default pam_profiles might not work for you.  I had to remove "sudo" since that wasn't configured in the docker image I was using.  Then login could proceed using just the "login" profile.